# numpy appending a 2D array to a 3D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i'd appreciate guidance on appending a 2D zeros array to a 3D array.  so as to add multiple layers to a 2x2 matrix.

```
#so, 
n = np.zeros((1,3,3,), np.ubyte)
n[0][0][1] = n[0][1][0] = 1
#return prints:
[[[0, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]]]
```

then how do you add another 2D array of zero elements to, in pseudocode:

```
a = np.zeros((3,3,), np.ubyte)
n = np.append(n, a)
#return prints:
 [[[0 1 0]
   [1 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]

  [[0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]
   [0 0 0]]]
```

and so on with the latter two lines to add any number of layers of the 3x3 2D matrix.

thank you in advance, lucas

Comment: repeatedly adding to an array is probably not a good idea, you'll create a new array at each step and the complexity will increase a lot. Why not create directly the needed number of values?

Comment: because i'm running a rather complicated set of instructions and i'd like to add another layer, but not another dimension, as needed.  instead of running the code twice to derive the maximum number of layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the arrays need to have the same shape. To join along an *existing* axis, you can use `np.concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate([n, a[None,...]], axis=0)
```

Note, this adds an extra dimension to `a`, or equivalently, we can extend along a new axis using `np.stack`:

```
np.stack([n[0], a], axis=0)
```

Note, in the above case, we *removed* a dimension from `n`.

As noted in the comments though, this is inefficient, this will scale very inefficiently (quadratic time on the total size), so keep that in mind.

Note, bot `arr[0]` and `arr[None, ...]` are "cheap" operations (constant time) and don't copy the underlying buffer, they create views.

Comment: yes, "n = np.concatenate([n, np.zeros((3,3,), np.ubyte)[None,...]], axis=0)" was the main command that worked great.  thank you again.

Comment: @lucas if you are actually using the expression `np.zeros((3,3,), np.ubyte)[None,...]]` you should just use `np.zeros((1,3,3), np.ubyte)`